# How do I write a script that re-execute a python script after it exits back to cmd prompt?

Tags: python

I have a pythonscript run.py that I currently run in the command line. However, I want a start.py script either in python (preferably) or .bat, php, or some other means that allows me to make it such that once run.py finishes running, the start.py script will reexecute the run.py script indefinitely, but ONLY after the run.py finishes executing and exits.

Sample Steps:
- Start.py is run that starts Run.py
- Run.py prints "hello" for 3 times after 5 seconds and exits normally or abnormally
- Start.py knows Run.py finished/closed and reexecutes run.py

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: This sounds more like something that should be IN the python script, to me. What's the use case for wanting it outside the script?

Comment: The run.py script could potentially have some kind of memory error that would cause an abnormal termination during execution. That is why I want a separate script that would know wnever run.py exits so it can be reexecuted. So even if run.py crashes, start.py will still be running.

Comment: Fix the memory error or `try...except` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a Python script, you *could* do this:

```
import os

while True:
  os.system('python run.py')
```

But a better approach would be to make your other Python file modular and run it properly via the second Python file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the first run interactive? Otherwise, you may use a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)

Comment: Non interactive, though maybe will become interactive in the future.